# CPU upgrade on a Dell Latitude E6400 results in in a dead system

Tags: laptop, cpu, dell-latitude, intel-core2

I have recently bought a Core 2 Duo T9900 for my Dell Latitude E6400 laptop, after having read [the following Dell community thread](https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General-Read-Only/E6400-Processor-Upgrade-Options/td-p/3577325).

Unfortunately, I obtain a blank screen after pressing the power button (no BIOS screen at all). I exclude possible assemblage mistakes, indeed re-installing the previous CPU (P8400) made my laptop live as before.

I also tried updating the BIOS, but the problems persists. Could I kindly ask for an opinion?

It is possible that the CPU is not really supported? Or damaged? In such a case, could a T9600 represent a possible reasonable alternative?

Comment: Possible bad processor.

Comment: For possible readers: I bought a new T9900 and it worked 100% smoothly. Very satisfied.